# How to edit SampleData.json - Access denied - Windwos 8 apps

Tags: c#, windows

Like the title states, how can I edit the SampleData.json file in the project's DataModel folder?
I get the error:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I'm using this to access the file:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation
```

I'm trying to edit the file for the purpose of adding new data to search within the Metro-app.

Comment: Are you trying to edit this file from Window explorer (or any other tool) or from Visual Studio? Did u check whether you have rights for this file?

Comment: Just one question though, if the app's source of data is the SampleData.json, then why can one not edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change any file in your application's installation folder. These files are read-only for your application. The only solution would be copying `SampleData.json` to the local folder.